# How do I send an SMS programmatically on Windows 7 and have my own personal mobile phone number show up as the sender?

Tags: api, windows-7, sms

I want to be able to programmatically send an SMS message from an app (coded in any language or using any protocol) on my Windows 7 OS that when sent will show my own personal mobile phone number as the sender.

I don't mind paying for a service or for an app that needs to be installed on both my PC and my Phone.  Applications like MightyText do very close to what I am looking for but do not as far as can see provide an actual API.

Services like Twillio or Clickatel provide very nice and clean API's but do not as far as can tell allow the 'Sending' phone number to be a personal mobile phone number.  These services seem to require a new dedicated phone number or short code be acquired through them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same exact requirement and found this service: https://smsgateway.me/
It's free (registration required), but it works like a charm.

If you know C#, here's a basic snippet (requires RestSharp):

```
var client = new RestClient("http://smsgateway.me/api/v3/");
var request = new RestRequest("messages/send", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("email", "your@email.com");
request.AddParameter("password", "Your Password");
request.AddParameter("device", 1234);
request.AddParameter("number", phoneNumber);
request.AddParameter("message", "Your message here.");
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Hi, smsgateway.me is fine, I tried your code and it works well, but how can I send message to multiple recipients? Thanks!

Comment: Is their service still up? I can't find the android app...